# Webcam color issue with mplayer

Tags: usb, webcam

I try to display (multiple) webcams on a hdmi screen with my Raspberry Pi B.

At first I used (since some month ago)  OpenCV solution for 2x C170 Logitech Webcam -> works flawless (5-6fps).

Now I want to upgrade my system to 4 webcams -> OpenCV performance breaks down to 0.5fps.

Therefore I installed a new Raspbian Version + mplayer and excecuted rpi-update / apt-get update + upgrade.

mplayer works fine with 3-4 fps with all 4 Webcams parallel (enough for me).

But the color of the Cam's is total off.

Someone has a solution?

[image: How it is]
[image: How it should be]

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 046d:c045 Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 046d:c223 Logitech, Inc. G11/G15 Keyboard / USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 020: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0605 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub [ednet]
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 05e3:0605 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub [ednet]
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 046d:c226 Logitech, Inc. G15 Refresh Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 1307:0165 Transcend Information, Inc. 2GB/4GB Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 046d:c227 Logitech, Inc. G15 Refresh Keyboard
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as you do.  I haven't tried to find a solution yet but will be watching here for answers.  If we don't find any, maybe we can pull resources if we need to resolve ourselves.

Comment: This question is to broad and has very little to do with Raspberry Pi. It is more about hardware and software issues that can happen on any OS

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adjusting mplayer at all?  From `man mplayer`:

```
(The following keys are valid only  when  using  a  hardware  accelerated  video  output  (xv,
(x)vidix, (x)mga, etc), the software equalizer (-vf eq or -vf eq2) or hue filter (-vf hue).)

      1 and 2
           Adjust contrast.
      3 and 4
           Adjust brightness.
      5 and 6
           Adjust hue.
      7 and 8
           Adjust saturation.
```

That's a pretty elaborate man page.  Probably daunting at first but if you are doing things with 4 cameras, no doubt worth a read.

From the looks of things the hue and saturation need serious adjustment.

Comment: I tried different settings, here is what i used: mplayer -fps 3 -nosound -nocache tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=320:height=240:device=/dev/video0:outfmt=YUY2 and experimented with :brightness=XX :saturation=xx etc. commands. No really good result.